# Can I use built-in Orchard features to send an email with attachments from code?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I inherited a project that was built on Orchard 1.6 and upgraded to 1.9. It relies heavily on `IMessageManager`, which is now deprecated, to send emails to users:

```cs
public void SendEmail(List<string> recipients, string subject, string body)
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    data.Add("Subject", subject);
    data.Add("Body", body);

    _messageManager.Send(recipients, "Event_Notification", "email", data);
}
```

Now I need to add dynamically generated file attachments (from a `MemoryStream`) to some of those mails. I'll probably have to completely rewrite this since I don't see any way to pass Attachments to the `MessageManager` but I'm not sure what to use as an alternative.

`Orchard.Email.Services.SmtpMessageChannel` already seems to do all the heavy lifting and it creates a `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` which can take an `AttachmentCollection` but the `void Process(IDictionary<string, object> parameters)` method still doesn't.

Should I extend this to do what I want? If so, how? Or is there already an easier way to just tell Orchard to send an email with a title, a body and a collection of attachments to a recipient?

Comment: There were a PR on GitHub recently, check it out: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/pull/7338

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy At a glance I think this change is meant to attach files that are stored on disk and expects filenames and paths to be passed as a string. I can use this to see which adjustments I would need to make though.